# Finding the flux of the vector $ \vec F=z\hat k$ across the boundary of a sphere centered around the origin having positive orientation

Tags: vector-analysis, surface-integrals, orientation, change-of-variable

I'm trying to find the flux of the vector $ \overrightarrow F=z\hat k$ across the boundary of a sphere $S$ centered around the origin with radius $\\a\\$ and having positive orientation. The answer is obviously the volume of the sphere $\frac{4 \pi a^3}{3}\\$ via the divergence theorem, but I'm trying to compute it directly using an appropriate surface integral. I observed that $S=\{f(x,y,z)=a^2\}$ where $\\f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2\\$ with gradient $\nabla{f}=2x\hat {i}+2y\hat {j}+2z\hat {k}$. The flux SHOULD be the double integral of $\overrightarrow F \cdot \nabla{f}=2z^2=2(a^2-x^2-y^2)\\$ over the projection of $S$ onto the $(x,y)$ plane $R=\{0\leq r\leq a;0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi\}$. But I keep getting $\pi a^4$! I do, however, get the correct answer if I don't include the $r$ in $dA=rdrd\theta$, which makes me suspect it's not necessary since the vector field $\overrightarrow F\\$ is only depends on $z$ and not $r$ and $\theta$. I feel very inadequate for not being able to figure out this triviality on my own, so let me down easy. Thank you.

Comment: If you project a hemisphere onto a disk, the surface area changes, so you can't just integrate $2(a^2-x^2-y^2)$ over the disk. Instead of $r\,dr\,d\theta$, you need your surface area element to represent area on the hemisphere; I believe it should be $ar/\sqrt{a^2-r^2}\,dr\,d\theta$.

Comment: I thought that $\overrightarrow n=\frac {\nabla f} {|| \nabla f||}\\$ and the surface area element $dS=||\nabla f||dA$ so that the integrand $\Big(\overrightarrow F \cdot \overrightarrow n \Big )dS=\bigg(\overrightarrow F\cdot\frac{\nabla f}{|| \nabla f||}\bigg )||\nabla f||dA=\Big(\overrightarrow F\cdot\nabla f\Big )dA$? (Assuming the direction of $\nabla f$ aligns with the orientation of the surface.) Would you recommend I always express these surfaces in parametric form to circumvent these subtleties?

Comment: I'm not sure what you use $dS$ and $dA$ to denote. It is probably easier to use the usual parameterization $(a\sin\theta\cos\phi,a\sin\theta\sin\phi,a\cos\theta) $ with area element $a^2\sin\theta\,d\theta\,d\phi$.